# Mathematicians ahead of their time?

Tags: soft-question, math-history, big-list, mathematicians

It is said that in every field there’s that person who was years ahead of their time. For instance, Paul Morphy (born 1837) is said to have retired from chess because he found no one to match his technique that very much resembled modern chess theory.

So, who was the Paul Morphy of mathematics?

Comment: Fermat, if one is to believe he actually did have a proof, and not just a marginal note... :)  Riemann was also supposed to have some pretty advanced stuff in his papers, IIRC.

Comment: [GAUSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carl_Friedrich_Gauss) is the first one that comes to mind for me

Comment: No one is ahead of their time.

Comment: @anorton: If Fermat would have come later, do you think that mathematics would have progressed to what it is today, which was largely affected by Fermat's work and the open questions left after his death?

Comment: @AsafKaragila: everybody lived for the years between birth and death, and no others. So yeah, nobody is *literally* ahead of their time. But I think the questioner has defined terms for this question sufficiently clearly that it's a *big* claim to say that no mathematician has ever been ahead of their time, in the way that Morphy is supposed to be for chess.

Comment: I have come to believe that there is a certain randomness to history, and Mathematics is not immune to this. I would not care to speculate how many Mathematicians have been ahead of their time, and have never had their work uncovered by future generations, because it was neglected, unpublished or unseen or just ignored by contemporaries. There may be something in the belief that truly great ideas will eventually re-emerge because there is a natural inevitability to the structure of Mathematics, but personally, I am not entirely confident that that is the case.

Comment: It's tempting to suggest [Shinichi Mochizuki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shinichi_Mochizuki), but it's too soon to know for sure.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I, personally, don't think Fermat *actually* had a proof of his famous statement.  Thus, I don't think that mathematics would have made any large jump.  (I mentioned him mainly as tongue-in-cheek...)  I, too, consider "living ahead of your time" a rather vague/ambiguous phrase, but I figure that the names I mentioned probably fit the idea for which the OP was looking.

Comment: Not exactly a mathematician, but how about Babbage?  I think it wasn't until computers were invented in the 20th century that people realized he'd had the key ideas in the 19th century (and had attempted to make a computer out of mechanical components). I'm not an expert on the history though.

Comment: @anorton: So many ideas were developed in order to try and prove FLT. If he would have lived today, why would these ideas have existed?

Comment: @AsafKaragila They would not.  (I'm saying that I don't really think bringing Fermat to the present would make a leap forward in math ability today due to the existence of a great mind who was limited by the ideas of his time...  I mentioned his name simply because I thought he might fit the type of person the OP was looking for, not necessarily what *I* think about Fermat.)

Comment: I suspect that if any one individual had not lived, someone else would have made the same discoveries. Perhaps not *all* the discoveries made by X would then have been made by Y if X had not lived; perhaps it would have been Y, Z, A', and Q'' that would have made those discoveries. In mathematics the truth is, so to speak, out there - it's a matter of turning over the rocks until something bites you. :-) Share and enjoy.

Comment: @MJD I haven't heard anything about Mochizuki's work that suggests that it's anything more than simply highly abstract, ambitious, and long.  Simply being the first with a big theory doesn't make you ahead of your time, not even if no one accepts it because of poor communication.  I mean, it's well-known what he has claimed to do; it's just that not much has been made of it because the barrier to learning the methods is so high.

Comment: According to the Wikipedia article on Robert Grossteste [ http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Grosseteste ], "The opinion of his own age, as expressed by Matthew Paris and Roger Bacon ... see in him the pioneer of a literary and scientific movement; not merely a great ecclesiastic who patronized learning in his leisure hours, but the first mathematician and physicist of his age." (although I'm not aware of any significant advances he made in maths). But c.f. also http://arxiv.org/abs/1403.0769

Answer (score 86, accepted):

I think Asaf makes a good argument against people like Galois and Cantor. As he says, if Cantor didn't develop set theory, who would have?  I think to find someone who is arguably ahead of their time, you need to find a mathematician whose work was ignored, and then reinvented in substantially similar fashion by others much later, so that you can say “look, this guy had it, but it was too soon, and then later someone else got credit for inventing the same thing.”  And so I nominate the logician [Charles Sanders Peirce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C.S._Peirce) (1839–1914).  When you study the early history of logic, it sometimes seems that every other sentence is “This work was anticipated by C.S. Peirce, whose contribution was unfortunately overlooked.”

To give a very narrow and incomplete idea of Peirce's accomplishments in mathematical logic I will quote briefly from the *Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy*:

> In 1870 Peirce published a long paper “Description of a Notation for the Logic of Relatives” in which he introduced for the first time in history, two years before Frege's *Begriffschrift*, a complete syntax for the logic of relations of arbitrary [arity]. In this paper the notion of the variable (though not under the name “variable”) was invented, and Peirce provided devices for negating, for combining relations (basically by building upon de Morgan's relative product and relative sum), and for quantifying existentially and universally. By 1883, along with his student O. H. Mitchell, Peirce had developed a full syntax for quantificational logic that was only a very little different… from the standard Russell-Whitehead syntax, which did not appear until 1910 (with no adequate citations of Peirce).
>
> Peirce introduced the material-conditional operator into logic, developed the Sheffer stroke and dagger operators 40 years before Sheffer, and developed a full logical system based only on the stroke function. As Garret Birkhoff notes in his *Lattice Theory* it was in fact Peirce who invented the concept of a lattice (around 1883).

(Burch, Robert, "[Charles Sanders Peirce](http://plato.stanford.edu/archives/sum2013/entries/peirce)", The Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy (Summer 2013 Edition), Edward N. Zalta (ed.))

Comment: I had a hard time deciding between Peirce and Ramanujan for best answer but while Ramanujan is one of the most brilliant mathematicians to ever live, Peirce fits the criteria I was looking for better. 

He suggested a cardinal arithmetic for infinite numbers, years before any work by Cantor.

He also showed how Boolean algebra could be done via a repeated sufficient single binary operation (logical NOR), anticipating Henry Sheffer by 33 years.

He also distinguished between first-order and second-order quantification, anticipating Zermelo by about two decades

Comment: And finally, in 1886 he saw that Boolean calculations could be carried out via electrical switches, anticipating Claude Shannon, who used the same principle to found the field of information theory, by more than 50 years. In my judgement, though less influential than the bigger names, Peirce is the Morphy of mathematics. @MJD thanks for your response.

Comment: Jeezus! Did he also invent LISP?

Comment: As far as I know, that wasn't invented until the early 1930s, by Alonzo Church.  But Peirce wrote around 100,000 (!!) pages of unpublished manuscripts, many of which are still uncatalogued, so it's possible that he anticipated Church and nobody knows it yet.

Comment: @MJD: I think you're confusing LISP with $\lambda$-calculus. Lisp was invented by McCarthy in the 1950's.

Comment: I'm being slightly facetious.

Comment: very good definition, this also points to Louis Bachelier, who invented Brownian motion and the modern theory of finance before Einstein, Samuelson, Merton and others.

Comment: This also points to some Indian mathematicians _e.g._, _Baudhayana_ who stated Pythagoras Theorem about 500 years before Pythagoras was born.

Comment: For more about Peirce's (1886!) observation that boolean logic could be implemented with electrical switches, see [my answer here on Electronics SE](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/321534/158571).  Shannon is often credited, but Peirce had the idea decades ahead.

Answer (score 132):

My top vote would be for [Ramanujan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Srinivasa_Ramanujan).  With severely limited resources, he was able to formulate deep number-theoretic identities that the top mathematicians in the field at the time hadn't the imagination to *conceive*, let alone the slightest clue to prove.  A close second would be [Evariste Galois](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evariste_galois)--dead at the age of 20, he had already established the foundations of what is now an entire algebraic theory named after him.  The world will never know what mathematics he could have discovered had he lived.

Comment: Galois may have produced excellent work, and he knew some of the following results and not others, but to say he was "ahead of his time" is very clearly false. The connection between polynomials and permutations was hinted at by Lagrange about 40 years prior, who himself was just using the theory of symmetric polynomials, known since at least Newton. Ruffini published very similar results to Galois and discovered many simply group theoretical results to do it. Abel did the same. Cauchy used permutations in his work on polynomial equations.

Comment: Ramanujan is _still_ ahead of his time.

Comment: Galois, all disputes about what"ahead of their time" means aside, was certainly ahead of his *age*. :)

Comment: @JackM: Dear Jack, My impression from reading a bit of his own writing, as well as Wussing's book on the history of group theory, was that Galois's approach was much more modern and structural than the earlier approaches (at least of Lagrange).  Do you have sources you could recommend   that elaborate on your comment?   Regards,

Comment: Both cases have a not exactly trivial component of drama

Comment: +1 for Ramanujan. It's important to not forget context. Ramanujan's early work was done effectively in a bubble. Even if a lot of what he did was re-discovery, there was no way for him to know that. He had no access to peers, no access to the state-of-the-art mathematics, and as far as I know, the academic culture on the Indian subcontinent was not well-suited for rigorous mathematical development.

Comment: @gjdanis Huh? If he was ahead of his time when he was alive, he will be ahead of his time for all eternity. It's *his* time: it's fixed.

Comment: Ramanujan was often not able to prove his intuitions. Still, an oustanding example.

Comment: Ramanujan was *behind* his time, practicing a style of math from a generation earlier. He was brilliant, no question, but not ahead of his time.

Comment: As proof that [Ramanujan](http://www-history.mcs.st-andrews.ac.uk/history/Biographies/Ramanujan.html) was ahead of his time, consider the following excerpt from an [article](http://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2014/04/140429125825.htm) in ScienceDaily: *"Mathematicians have found a framework for the celebrated Rogers-Ramanujan identities and their arithmetic properties, solving another long-standing mystery stemming from the work of Indian math genius Srinivasa Ramanujan. The findings yield a treasure trove of algebraic numbers and formulas to access them."*

Comment: According to the mathematicians Ramanujan never had shown his methods of proof of his rediscoveries. Whatever he did back in India was, well to say loosely, by intuition. No trace of rigor was there. He didn't showed his methods to any other person. Only the results. It was only after he had gone to England that he learnt to 'prove' something. So how can he be a mathematician ahead of his time? Mathematics, in a strict sense, is advanced not by unproved hypothesis but by rigorous proof of this hypothesis. He s probably an effective example but not the best one.

Comment: @WilliamHilbert, but you have to admit that the guy's conjecture-making was incredible. There's imo no reason to demand that every mathematician be a jack-of-all-trades. If someone is magically able to come up with these incredible conjectures that somehow amazingly usually turn out to be true, but cannot prove anything for their life, I say: "Let them conjecture!"

Comment: +1 for Ramanujan. Most comments regarding Ramanujan's lack of proofs are somewhat misleading. Ramanujan had rigorous proofs for most of his results and some were conjectures (and he was very honest about these things). The reason he did not provide proofs was lack of paper. He was too poor to afford paper and dis all his derivations on slate and only stored results on precious paper which later became famous as Ramanujan's Notebooks. In England he did get financial support and he published some proofs, but unfortunately he did not have much time to publish all the proofs.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh: In the letter dated 27.02.1913 Ramanujan wrote (to Hardy), "...you will not be able to follow my methods of proof if I indicate the lines on which I proceed in a single letter. You may ask how you can accept results based on wrong premises. What I tell you is this. Verify the results I give and if they agree with your results, got by treading on the groove in which the present day mathematicians move, you should at least grant that there may be some truths in my fundamental basis."

Comment: @user170039: that letter is famous and I have read it in full. But I have seen proofs given by him in his collected papers. I think here he is referring to his handling of divergent series based on which he obtained many results. I must say Ramanujan did not have the ability to explain his technique in very clear terms. On the other hand Hardy was a master expositor and wrote very beautiful English (see his *A Mathematician's Apology* and *A Course of Pure Mathematics*). And it is Hardy who helped him write his proofs (in papers) which were understandable by general public.

Comment: @user170039: also you can see that the letter essentially says that the technique of Ramanujan could not be explained in one letter and this is very true. In fact this is true of any significant theorem which is new (example: proof of irrationality of $\zeta(3)$ where people did doubt Apery initially). But when Hardy spent good amount of time with Ramanujan he did get to know some of his arguments and convinced Ramanujan to write papers using modern notation and language.

Comment: At the time of his (untimely) death, Évariste was not on a path to create more math.

Comment: Chess parallel of (Paul Morphy = Galois) vs (Fischer [in his prime] = Gauss) vs (Ramanujan = Tal [when healthy] or Kasparov or Carlsen).  Unclear how Steinitz, who was ahead of his time, or Capablanca who was an *intuitive player* would analogize to Ramanujan.

Answer (score 68):

For sheer *amount* of time ahead, may I suggest [Brahmagupta](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahmagupta) (597–668), [Jayadeva](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jayadeva_%28mathematician%29) (950 ~ 1000) and [Bhāskara II](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bh%C4%81skara_II) (1114 ~ 1185), Indian mathematicians whose work in indeterminate quadratic equations and many other branches predated European attempts by more than *half a millennium*.

In particular, consider their work on [chakravala](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chakravala_method), an elegant and powerful method to find solutions to Pell's equation $x^2 = Ny^2 + 1$. Circa 1150, Bhāskara II had a solution for the case $N=61$, while in Europe it was given *as a challenge* by Fermat and first solved in 1657. More than one hundred years later (in 1766), Lagrange's "general" method to solve this problem was still much more complicated and inelegant than *chakravala*, which for its application requires nothing but elementary arithmetic.

Comment: I can't tell whether those Indian mathematicians were ahead of their time, or Europe was behind the times ;-)

Comment: @SteveJessop: Europe was far, far behind the times. IMO.

Comment: Also calculus, apparently: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yuktibh%C4%81%E1%B9%A3%C4%81. If anyone can shed some light on this book, I'd be very grateful. Translation available from Springer: http://www.springer.com/mathematics/history+of+mathematics/book/978-1-84882-072-2

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_mathematics says *Indian mathematics emerged in the Indian subcontinent[1] from 1200 BC[2] until the end of the 18th century. In the classical period of Indian mathematics (400 AD to 1600 AD), important contributions were made by scholars like Aryabhata, Brahmagupta, Mahāvīra (mathematician), Bhaskara II, Madhava of Sangamagrama and Nilakantha Somayaji.*

Comment: The definition is "ahead of their time" so being ahead of someone else's time (i.e. European time) doesn't cut it.

Answer (score 56):

Firstly, its worth recalling what Asaf writes in the comments:

> Yes, pioneers are often considered "ahead of their time", but we
>   forget that the reason we think of them as ahead of their time is that
>   their ideas were thoroughly developed later because they required
>   several decades to be processed by the mathematical community at
>   large.

That being said, I think that everyone is bound by the dominant paradigm in which they're surrounded; yet somehow, certain key individuals are able to break with this paradigm just enough to do the ground-breaking work that they're remembered for. When this happens, their insights often seem to "come out of the blue," and it sometimes takes the wider mathematical community many years to catch up. Here's a couple of examples that I find particularly compelling.

**Jean Baptiste Joseph Fourier (1768 – 1830)** was one of the first people to think of a function as, well, an arbitrary *function*, rather than an explicitly given rule; hence the functions $f : [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $g : [0,2] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ given by $x \mapsto x^2$ are actually *different.* This was necessary to develop what we now call the Fourier transform, the then-groundbreaking (frankly I think its still groundbreaking) idea that just about every function $I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ can be expressed as a superposition of sine and cosine waves, where $I$ is a real interval. Even today, the Fourier transform is among the most important of tools in the arsenal of many engineers, physicists, and applied mathematicians; and the realization that functions with different domains need to be distinguished was a crucial step toward the pure mathematics of today that we know and love.

**Georg Cantor (1845 – 1918)** is, of course, the grandfather of modern set theory. Among other things, Cantor invented the ordinals, proved that every set could be well-ordered; and, building on Fourier's idea of a function as-an-arbitrary function, Cantor was able to formulate the concept of two sets being *equipotent*. Cantor realized that both $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$ are equipotent to $\mathbb{N}$, and later, much to his shock, that $\mathbb{R}$ is not! I think he also discovered the $\aleph$ indexing of the cardinal numbers. Writing in a mathematical climate that was fiercely constructive and deeply suspicious of infinity, Cantor's work was largely ignored, and many of the top mathematicians of the day openly ridiculed his ideas. Nonetheless, he kept on working on his set theory (which he believed had theological significance) until the very end of his days, especially the continuum hypothesis. Its sucks that Cantor's work wasn't recognized sooner; once we started paying attention, pure mathematics was changed forever.

There's a lot more people I wanted to talk about (especially Godel, Samuel Eilenberg, Saunders Mac Lane, Garret Birkhoff, Alexander Grothendieck, and William Lawvere) but maybe I'll just leave it there.

Comment: Nice examples.${}$

Comment: Cantor was before his time? How so? If he would have come later, who would have developed set theory?

Comment: @AsafKaragila, I don't get your point. If Cantor had come later, someone else would have developed set theory. **Later.** But as far as I know, nobody was thinking along the lines Cantor was thinking **at that time.**

Comment: It's completely unclear that anyone would have developed set theory other than Cantor. Do you have anyone in mind, someone who wasn't thoroughly influenced by Cantor to begin with? Yes, pioneers are often considered "ahead of their time", but we forget that the reason we think of them as ahead of their time is that their ideas were thoroughly developed later because they required several decades to be processed by the mathematical community at large. If Cantor would have been born five decades later, it might as well been the case that set theory was five decades later. But we'll never know.

Comment: @AsafKaragila, I don't disagree. (Except with the statement that its completely unclear that anyone would have developed set theory other than Cantor; I think its clear that set theory would eventually have been developed, perhaps by the first logicians, trying to make rigorous the informal semantics they were giving to their formal systems.)

Comment: Or type theory would have been more prevalent, and we would all be doing type theory today.

Comment: @AsafKaragila, sorry I don't know enough about type theory to know whether or not that could have happened. By the way, I quoted your comment here in my answer; I hope you don't mind.

Comment: I don't mind, I don't know a lot about it either. But it is what Russell and Whitehead were suggesting as a foundational basis. In the absence of good logic and set theory alternative, it might have been developed faster and sooner. So when Cantor arrives some decades later, he's already drawn to this ideas and doesn't develop set theory. In that universe I didn't become a mathematician, but I did manage to take over the world and kill the evil aliens that destroyed Mt. Everest.

Comment: @Asaf: but without there already being activity in set theory, Russell and Whitehead maybe don't see the *need* for a foundational basis because the problems they set out to solve aren't discovered yet (and Zermelo was tragically killed in crossfire with the aliens shortly after the Battle of Kathmandu). So maybe Frege was the man ahead of his time, in that he didn't get much traction for his project to formalise set theory. Thanks to a catchy paradox Russell did get traction :-)

Comment: @AsafKaragila I think Cantor is a good example because his ideas were so new and radical that many established mathematicians--such as Kronecker, Poincaré, Brouwer, and Weyl--rejected them.

Comment: I'd love to hear your thoughts about the other mathematicians you mentioned.  Please write more!

Comment: @littleO, thanks for your encouragement. I might write a little more when I find the time.

Answer (score 50):

I'm surprised to see no one here has nominated Hermann Grassmann, who essentially invented the subject of Linear Algebra. His mathematical work was little appreciated in its time, and it took decades before it gained acceptance.

From Wikipedia:

"Fearnley-Sander (1979) describes Grassmann's foundation of linear algebra as follows:

'   The definition of a linear space (vector space)... became widely known around 1920, when Hermann Weyl and others published formal definitions. In fact, such a definition had been given thirty years previously by Peano, who was thoroughly acquainted with Grassmann's mathematical work. Grassmann did not put down a formal definition --- the language was not available --- but there is no doubt that he had the concept.
Beginning with a collection of 'units' $e_1, e_2, e_3, \dots ,$ he effectively defines the free linear space which they generate; that is to say, he considers formal linear combinations $a_1e_1 + a_2e_2 + a_3e_3 + \dots$ where the $a_j$ are real numbers, defines addition and multiplication by real numbers [in what is now the usual way] and formally proves the linear space properties for these operations. ... He then develops the theory of linear independence in a way which is astonishingly similar to the presentation one finds in modern linear algebra texts. He defines the notions of subspace, linear independence, span, dimension, join and meet of subspaces, and projections of elements onto subspaces.

...few have come closer than Hermann Grassmann to creating, single-handedly, a new subject.'

...Comprehension of Grassmann awaited the concept of vector spaces which then could express the multilinear algebra of his extension theory. A. N. Whitehead's first monograph, the Universal Algebra (1898), included the first systematic exposition in English of the theory of extension and the exterior algebra. With the rise of differential geometry the exterior algebra was applied to differential forms."

Hence, Hermann Grassmann is my nomination for a mathematician ahead of his time.

Comment: Grassmann did this work for his PhD, but his advisor (Mobius) didn't understand or appreciate it and failed him! That pretty much ended Grassmann's mathematical career - he changed fields and went on to be a noted linguist.

Comment: He knew that he was ahead of his time, and that people just did not notice it - a quote from his revised version of the work on "Ausdehnungslehre" (1862): *But I know and feel obliged to state ... that even if this work should again remain unused for another seventeen years or even longer, ...it will be brought forth from the dust of oblivion and when ideas now dormant will bring forth fruit.*. I mainly knew him for his pioneering work in *geometric* algebra, and would have mentioned him if you had not already done this (+1)

Comment: This isn't quite correct. See [the addendum on this MO answer.](http://mathoverflow.net/a/121601/40804)

Comment: @NickAlger: Only your last statement is true, please correct. Mike: Thanks for linking.

Comment: @Nick Alger: sounds like what happened to Louis Bachelier with his Poincaré supervisor!

Answer (score 37):

[Archimedes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedes#Archimedes_Palimpsest), for basically discovering [calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Method_of_Mechanical_Theorems) eighteen centuries before either Newton or Leibniz. See [Archimedes Palimpsest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedes_Palimpsest#Mathematical_content) for more details. :-)

Comment: It *says on that very Wiki page* (on the second line) that the method of exhaustion (which I assume you're referring to) was invented by Eudoxus (or at least known to him).

Comment: @JackM: No. That's not what the Palimpsest is about.

Comment: Archimedes developed the method of exhaustion by inventing heuristics which resemble the methods of integral calculus. That's why he could be considered ahead of his time.

Comment: Also, Archimedes was the first to find the tangent to a curve, other than a circle, in a method akin to differential calculus. However saying he 'discovered' calculus is an overstatement as the Fundamental Principle of Calculus was only discovered by Newton/Leibniz

Comment: In a similar vein, one could say that the Indian mathematicians of the 12th (Bhaskara II - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bh%C4%81skara_II#Calculus) and later the 15th centuries (Madhava - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Madhava_of_Sangamagrama#Calculus) were ahead of *European* time. Although I've yet to read a good English translation (too expensive) of it, so I say how close it really is to 'calculus'.

Answer (score 24):

Is nobody going to even *mention* **Blaise Pascal**?!

Just check out a few of his accomplishments and see how far ahead of his time he was:

- He made a fundamental contribution to **projective geometry** when he was 16(!) years old (appreciating the brilliance of Desargues's contributions at a time when analytic geometry was far more popular)
- His correspondence with Pierre de Fermat basically *invented* **Probability Theory**
- He independently invented one of the first mechanical calculators
- His work with fluids generalized the results of Evangelista Torricelli

(Also note the similarity to Paul Morphy -- Pascal gave up math by the age of 30)

And that's not even mentioning his contributions to Philosophy & Theology--frankly, few people span the Dewey Decimal System like my boy BLAISE.

And there's that triangle of his...

Comment: I have a soft spot for Pascal, however "his" triangle was already known in India and China.

Comment: I'm don't know enough to either agree or disagree with him, but Devlin in *The Unfinished Game* seems to think that Fermat was the teacher and Pascal the student in their correspondence.

Comment: @joeA, no way, Pascal was ahead of God!

Answer (score 20):

Diophantus of Alexandria, who invented a form of algebraic notation and much of what we now call Diophantine equations. His work was nearly ignored in his own time and rediscovered hundreds of years later by al-Khwarizmi and others.

His use of [παρισὀτης](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adequality) (as mentioned in another answer) anticipated early versions of differential calculus 1300 years later.

Answer (score 17):

Simon Stevin (1548 – 1620) had the unbelievable insight of thinking of an arbitrary number in terms of its unending decimal expansion. He was ahead of his time in the sense that the full significance of what he did was not appreciated until the 1870s when more abstract versions of the construction of the reals were given by Charles Méray and others. Unending decimals inspired Newton to introduce more general power series. The rest is history.

Another amazing contribution of Stevin was his argument immediately recognizable as a proof of the intermediate value theorem, which was not "officially" proved until the 1820s by Cauchy. See [this article](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s10699-012-9285-8). Here he was ahead of his time by at least 200 years.

Comment: Didn't he also discover the quadratic formula as we know it today?

Answer (score 15):

Girard Desargues more or less invented projective geometry in the 17th century, but nobody else paid significant attention to the topic until the 19th century.  You might say he was both ahead of and behind his time, since he developed his geometry in a classical style (without any interpretation using numeric coordinates) at just about the time Cartesian coordinates were coming into vogue.

Answer (score 14):

I would like to add a name that nobody has mentioned: [Alexandre Grothendieck](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_Grothendieck).

The name comes to my mind not only for what he achieved in his *active* career, which was itself pathbreaking and quite visionary, but rather for the *Esquisse d’un Programme*, in particular for how it is described by people that worked on it. For example, this is what Leila Schneps of Université de Paris VI said about it:

*“It was a wild expression of mathematical imagination, [...] I loved it. I was bowled over, and I wanted to start working on it right away. [...] Some of it doesn’t even seem to make sense at first, but then you work for two years, and you go back and look at it, and you say, ‘He knew this’.”* [p.1205 - [Jackson - The Life of Alexandre Grothendieck](http://www.ams.org/notices/200410/fea-grothendieck-part2.pdf)]

Answer (score 11):

I would go for Louis Bachelier, who developed and conceptualized what we today know as Brownian motion. His thesis *The Theory of Speculation* applied the idea of a random walk to describe and model stock options, predating Einstein's work on physical diffusion and brownian motion which itself came before the idea of a Markov process was formalized by Andrey Markov in 1906.

Comment: While we're talking about physics, Emmy Noether's derivation of the laws of conservation from symmetry is definitely ahead of her time in my view. And perhaps still ahead of our time.

Comment: @AmadeusDrZaius, Louis Bachelier wrote his thesis under Henri Poincaré, the leading mathematician of his time, not in physics. By the way, Poincaré did not understand Bachelier's work and did nothing to help him.

Answer (score 9):

Fermat, whose [adequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adequality) anticipated the calculus by several decades.

Comment: Archimedes of Syracuse also anticipated calculus more than 1800 years before Newton and Leibniz. Madhava of Sangamagrama anticipated trigonometric Taylor series > 200 years before Newton

Answer (score 7):

What about George Boole (1815-1864) with boolean algebra (1847) that didn't have any practical use until the introduction of computers?

Comment: Define "practical use".

Comment: Absolutely. George Boole, a self taught mathematical, whose impact in tech/digital revolution is magical. In fact, Clause Shannon's famous Masters thesis (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Symbolic_Analysis_of_Relay_and_Switching_Circuits) established the Boolean algebra into wider realm of applications.

Answer (score 6):

There is a book that claims that while Babbage invented the Analytic Engine, it was actually Ada Lovelace that conceived of an abstract "Science of Operations" as she called it. She invented this well before a working computer capable of implementing her ideas was constructed, and well before Turing et al., so objectively her theory was ahead of her time.

I don't know how well developed her Science of Operations was. Does anyone know more about this? I am finding it hard to find many details.

Answer (score 5):

Though I'm not sure to what extent I agree with the premise of the question, I'd nevertheless like to mention [Élie Cartan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89lie_Cartan).

Much of Cartan's work was not fully appreciated [until late in his life](http://www-groups.dcs.st-and.ac.uk/~history/Biographies/Cartan.html).  He was the first to introduce the concepts of [holonomy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holonomy) and [spinors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spinor).  He defined and classified the [symmetric spaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_space).  His technique of [moving frames](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_frame) proved to be very successful, and I would say that his [Method of Equivalence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartan%27s_equivalence_method) was very forward-thinking.

And really, this is such an incomplete list of his accomplishments.

(As an aside, I'm surprised to see no mention of [Grothendieck](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_Grothendieck) at the time of this writing... or, separately, any of the developers of hyperbolic geometry.)

Comment: Grothendieck was a mathematician of astonishing insight but he was precisely *of* his times.  If you look at any of his contributions, they are well-motivated by existing ideas, even if they are radical abstractions of them.  Also, although he was polarizing, he had a huge following throughout his career.  Any rejection of his methods has to be seen as an understandable resistance to having one's foundations overturned and the prevailing values of one's subject (apparently) questioned.

Answer (score 5):

Archimedes was mentioned by Lucian for his [palimpsest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedes_Palimpsest) (which *does* show his technique for computing volumes of bodies by adding up infinitely many infinitessimals), and I agree, but I would like to say more.

I think it must also be mentioned that many believe Archimedes to be the inventor of the [Antikythera device](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antikythera_mechanism), which was very far ahead of its time, by much more than a millenium, according to the engineers who inspected it. Though not strictly a work of mathematics, it did involve complicated mathematics and does demonstrate (if one accepts Archimedes' authorship) that he was a mathematician far ahead of his time.

It is also interesting to note that both the palimpset and the device are badly decayed ancient artifacts which we had no knowledge of before discovering them (except for perhaps a vague line by someone like Pliny the Elder - I can't remember who exactly), and which completely shocked historians and mathematicians/engineers with their sophistication for the time.

Therefore one wonders what other insights or marvels Archimedes was responsible for which, if discovered, would engender similar degrees of incredulity and wonder. It is assured that we do not possess his complete works - probably by a wide margin, given the accounts of how dedicated to and driven by his work he was; of what remains outstanding, how much do you think we would find utterly outstanding?

**EDIT**

Actually, even more needs to be said. Archimedes also presaged exponential notation with his notion of myriad when trying to figure out [how many grains of sand are in the universe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Sand_Reckoner), and thereby developed techniques for dealing with enormous quantities, and in the estimation of some invented the odometer. Both achievements are also quite far ahead of their time. I'm sure even more can be said, but I couldn't leave out mention of these notable examples.

Answer (score 5):

With the discussion of what is actually meant by "ahead of their time" in mind, and even if he is not the "father of computing" as is often claimed, I still think that [Alan Turing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alan_Turing) deserves a mention for the intuition that nonlinearities may give rise to complexities and unstable vacuum solutions, *and* for the intuition that such phenomena (through reaction--diffusion mechanisms) are responsible for observable biological phenomena such as the patterning of animal hides. Only recently has *physical, non-computational evidence* of this been found.

In his famous 1952 paper [The Chemical Basis of Morphogenesis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Chemical_Basis_of_Morphogenesis) he describes a reaction--diffusion model that he argues can describe patterning in animal hides. Due to limitations in computer power at the time, his numerical investigations were limited to a one-dimensional model.

Modern computer simulations in 2D do indeed produce patterns that are strikingly similar to a wealth of animal hide patterns, and also other patterns in nature such as sand dunes. Importantly, *Turing had no means to compute these patterns*, but understood that his model could give rise to them, via the effects of nonlinearities, which was in itself a ground breaking idea.

Answer (score 5):

I propose Bolzano. His understanding of mathematical rigor in analysis was certainly much more advanced than that of most of his peers. For instance, he correctly criticized the rigor of even the great C F Gauss's proof of the fundamental theorem of algebra. Among other examples I could cite, he proved the Extreme Value Theorem in the 1830's using what is now called the Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem. This was rediscovered by Weierstrass in the 1860's.

Another example of his insight is his example of a continuous nowhere differentiable function in 1831. His construction was essentially fractal in nature. Not only did it take until 1872 for Weierstrass to publish his famous example of the same kind of function, but Weierstrass' example was regarded as controversial and shocking all those years later.

Answer (score 4):

Obviously every mathematician who did something extraordinary in mathematics was ahead of his time.
So , I suppose a very good example is [Leibniz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gottfried_Wilhelm_Leibniz)

He discovered Calculus which is something groundbreaking in the field of mathematics.
(and not only mathematics actually)

Comment: I'm looking for mathematicians who were way ahead of other mathematicians of their time, maybe to the extent of their work or its implications not being understood. And I'm not sure about Leibniz discovering Calculus as Newton usually shares the credit.

Comment: RAMANUJAN and EULER .. Euler invented things like Borel transform FOurier analysis , Laplace transform and many other ideas which were studied hundred years after

Comment: @If $x$ mathematicians were alive those years except Leibniz, he was ahead of $x-1$ mathematicians at least ($1$ stands for Newton). I think they are enough.

Comment: @JoseGarcia, pretty sure Fourier invented Fourier analysis.

Comment: The fact that Leibnitz and Newton each developed calculus within a few years of each other means, I think, that each stands as witness that the other's work on the subject was very much *of* its time. If "being the first to do something" is evidence of being ahead of your time then hopefully anyone awarded a PhD in mathematics is ahead of their time, extraordinary or not :-) A more fruitful definition might be, to do something that your contemporaries consider wrong or pointless, but that some time significantly later is realised to have been important.

Comment: @SteveJessop Calculus is not just "something"

Comment: @KonstantinosGaitanas: no matter how important the "thing", I don't see how "doing something at more or less the same time that someone else did it" can be described as "being ahead of your time". Being very clever and doing something incredibly important and novel, sure. But that is not what the idiom means and neither is it how the questioner characterises it for the purpose of the question.

Comment: FOURIER invented the general method but i think that euler and bernoulli had used the fouire method to the solution of the string problem :D

Answer (score 4):

I am going to vote for [Kurt Gödel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kurt_G%C3%B6del). Not for his groundbreaking results in logics, but for his early understanding of problems with computational complexity.

Specifically this was mentioned in his [lost letter](http://rjlipton.wordpress.com/the-gdel-letter/) to John von Neumann in 1956.

Only 15 years later, [Stephen Cook](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stephen_Cook) and [Richard Karp](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richard_M._Karp) redeveloped these ideas, and formulated them preceisly, e.g. the [Karps list of 21 NP complete problems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karp%27s_21_NP-complete_problems).

Answer (score 3):

My vote goes to Carl Friedrich Gauß: "Mathematical historian Eric Temple Bell said that had Gauss published all of his discoveries in a timely manner, he would have advanced mathematics by fifty years" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carl_Friedrich_Gauss#Personality)

See also

- [Unpublished Discoveries by Gauss that Were Later Rediscovered and Attributed to Other Mathematicians](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/117232/unpublished-discoveries-by-gauss-that-were-later-rediscovered-and-attributed-to) .

Answer (score 2):

All names mentioned above deserve credit! A notable mathematician was only the one ahead of his time, when his/her mathematics changed the world. I would add, for my money, John Nash.

Comment: I think John Nash is a particularly hard sell. His two main contributions are Nash Equilibirium and the Nash Embedding Theorem. His treatment of the Nash Equilibrium seems to have been very similar to some earlier work by Neumann. I think you would also have a hard time arguing that the Nash Embedding Theorem was ahead of it's time, since he did not even give the first correct proof of the theorem.

Comment: I guess you are right. I am familiar with van Neumann's book. On grounds of Neumann's earlier work, yes, I agree that Nash is hard to sell. How about on grounds of results? His equilibrium changed the face of modern economics. With these said, I guess you are right.

Comment: @Mihai that argument makes a better case that Neumann was ahead of his time. Economics was ready for Nash.

Answer (score 2):

Rufus Isaacs' work in dynamic/differential game theory was substantially more advanced than the control theory work of the time. In fact, it can be argued that most control theory folks *still* don't understand it.

Answer (score 2):

I am pretty sure, Clause Shannon and Alan Turing will also find a place in this list. They may not be bracketed purely as mathematicians, but as applied mathematicians, they surely deserve a place here.

Answer (score 1):

You can have people 'ahead of their time'.  What really happens is you have 'mainstream maths', and than a whole lot of eccentrics who are 'doing their thing', which may or may not be where maths will be in 20 or 30 years time.

There are several things one has to note here.  Some of us are just not really good at sitting down and writing theorms and proofs etc.  I have a degree in physics, which means you approach the world in a different way to what the mathematicians do.  None the same, you can do 'real maths', but do it without having to prove the tedia involved.

The sorts of things i needed for my studies in weights and measures, and number-bases (i use base 120 natively), etc, i had to go back something like 100 years and look at what the eccentrics were doing.

So, really, people really can be 20 or 30 years ahead of the mathematics, you just got to be in the right crowd of eccentrics.

Answer (score 1):

The problem of *key distribution* is one that has historically afflicted cryptography. No matter how secure a cipher is, it can be compromised if the key is not shared securely.

With businesses growing in size and having more keys to be delivered, key distribution became the major issue for post-WWII cryptographers. The Diffie-Hellman-Merkle key exchange scheme (1976) was a brilliant attempt at tackling this problem by using one-way functions in modular arithmetic.

A year later, in 1977, this idea was further developed by Rivest, Shamir and Adleman into what is known today as RSA — a system of public key crytography which uses an *asymmetric key* rather than a symmetric one (which had been the norm in all of history).

---

**However, one man, [Clifford Cocks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clifford_Cocks), had already invented the “RSA” algorithm back in 1973.**

Another mathematician, James Ellis, working at the UK's top-secret Government Communications Headquarters (GCHQ) had already invented the idea of *non-secret encryption*, anticipating Diffie, Hellman and Merkle by several years.

Clifford Cocks, then a recent PhD graduate from Cambridge, was among the mathematicians recruited to attempt to find the required one-way functions for public key cryptography to work. He realized that prime factorization is the answer and developed the same solution that would later become known as the RSA encryption algorithm.

Although Cocks’s idea was one of the GCHQ’s most formidable discoveries, it suffered from the problem of being ahead of its time. Neither the GCHQ nor the NSA with whom the discovery was shared were able to find a way to use the algorithm, and they simply treated it as classified information.

The work was finally declassified approximately 25 years after Cocks’s discovery.

[Source: [The Code Book: The Science of Secrecy from Ancient Egypt to Quantum Cryptography](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/17994.The_Code_Book)]

Comment: I wouldn't say that a four year gap is "ahead of his time". Certainly not in mathematics.

Comment: @AsafKaragila It is not the amount of years which makes it ahead of its time. It is the fact that the research was simply classified, effectively ignored at the time it was made.

Comment: On the contrary, the fact the same work was discovered "about the same time" by other people means that it was ***not*** ahead of its time.  But rather a fruit ripe for the taking by the mathematics that led to its discovery. Which *was* public knowledge. Being ignored is not the "decisive factor" when talking about people who were ahead of their time. It's an important one, but not the most important one.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I see your point. However, a factor that *is* decisive and gives this discovery a lot of weight is its ground-breaking nature. This is arguably the most important discovery in cryptography to date and has revolutionized the world of digital security. The discovery being made by Cocks and later by others who received the credit makes him a mathematician ahead of his time.